# Do I need to make every method synchronized in a Singleton class?

Tags: java, singleton, synchronized

In below multiple thread programming example, `Replacer` class can be accessed by multiple threads at the same time, So I made the class singleton and made `getInstance()` method synchronized. Do I also need to make the `replaceNum()` method synchronized, assuming the method will also be called by multiple threads?

```
public class Replacer {

  private static Replacer replacer = null;
  private List<Integer> nums;

  private Replacer() {
    nums = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public static synchronized Replacer getInstance() {
    if (replacer == null) {
      replacer = new Replacer();
    }

    return replacer;
  }

  // Do I need to make below method synchronized?
  public void replaceNum(List<Integer> newNums) {
    if (nums.size() > 0) {
      nums.remove(nums.size() - 1);
    }

    nums.addAll(newNums);
  }
}
```

Comment: No, you don't need to make it synchronized, because you never structurally change the list.

Comment: @AndyTurner - `nums.remove()`? `nums.add()`? :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder and when is that executed?

Comment: @AndyTurner - If you're pointing out a *logical* flaw in the presented class, I'd say that was rather too subtle to be useful to the OP, all due respect. :-)

Comment: Sure, in order to avoid concurrent modifications of the values in your `nums` array and therefore unpredictable result of the method you have to make it synchronized. Yep, and I think you have to have a list instead of an int as an input to your method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule isn't special for singletons. It's purely:

- Does the method need to support multiple threads calling it, and
- Does it do anything that will fail if multiple threads call it at Just The Wrong Time

The answer for your `replaceNum` is "yes, it needs synchronization" (and at the method level would make sense, as basically everything within it needs to be synchronized) since it uses an `ArrayList`'s methods, which are not thread-safe. As [the Javadoc says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized.** If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.)

So that method needs to synchronize access to that `ArrayList`.

Given a blanket statement like that, you have to assume none of the methods is thread-safe unless it explicitly says that it *is*. (Similarly, unless a class explicitly says it *is* thread-safe, you have to assume it isn't.)

Answer (score 1):

(Answer was written for [an earlier version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52281164/2)).

No, you don't need to make it synchronized, because you never structurally change the list.

You only add to the list if it's not empty. So you never add the first element to it.

This is almost certainly a logical flaw, but it answers the question as written.

Assuming you fix the logic, and you can add elements to the list, and you want to call it from multiple threads, yes, it should be synchronized.

But the reason for this is *not* that `ArrayList` is clearly documented as requiring synchronization when accessed from multiple threads (although indicates that synchronization must be involved in some way):

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized**. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, itmust be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.)

It is that you are performing compound actions on the list: *if the list isn't empty, remove its last element; then add a new element*.

That first bit (*if the list isn't empty, remove its last element*) can be messed up by multiple threads. For example, two threads can simultaneously find the list has size 1; then one thread removes the last element before the other; then the other thread tries to remove a now-removed element. Kaboom.

Or, the adding can be messed up if both threads find that the list is empty, and so don't try to remove anything; then both add, and you end up with two elements on the list.

Even if you use `Collections.synchronizedList`, as recommended in the documentation of `ArrayList`, this doesn't fix your problem. It is important to realize that the quote above is what you have to do to preserve the invariants *of `ArrayList`*; it does nothing to enforce invariants of *your* code.

You need to be able to execute this logic *atomically*. The whole thing is done like a "single action", by one thread with exclusive access to the list. This is accomplished by synchronization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answers are all excellent. But I have to make the hard decision to accept the earliest one.

Answer (score 0):

Any method that changes the state of the shared instance should be marked `synchronized` to be safe. `synchronized` methods "check out" a lock on the instance of the class (`this`), and all synchronized methods take control of that same lock, so using this keyword on multiple methods will do the job. Although, you should try to `synchronize` on a small piece of code if you expect it to be called many times. In general, you should synchronize as little code as possible for best performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answers are all excellent. But I have to make the hard decision to accept the earliest one.

Comment: Thanks so much! The one you chose was much more informative, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple accesses to the method call (writes and reads), then, yes, you would need to use `synchronized` because `ArrayList` is not a thread-safe implementation inherently.

Something like:

```
public synchronized void replaceNum(List<Integer> newNums) {
    if (nums.size() > 0) {
        nums.remove(nums.size() - 1);
    }
    nums.addAll(newNums);
}
```

Another option is that you could use `Vector` instead and that makes your implementation thread-safe. But, it has its own performance issues. In general, thread-safe implementations have slower performance compared to its counterparts that are NOT thread-safe.

Comment: synchronized (this)  === public synchronized void replaceNum

Comment: Thanks for noting that.. Edited the answer.. Because we don't have anymore code above the synchronized block in this case, yes, we could use the keyword over the method itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answers are all excellent. But I have to make the hard decision to accept the earliest one.